# Routing Error Payanyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, маршрутизация

Установил gem payanyway(https://github.com/ssnikolay/payanyway) После того, как платеж прошел успешно, открывается страница /success, а там Routing Error.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount Payanyway::Engine => '/payanyway'
  ....
end
```

rake routes

```
Routes for Payanyway::Engine
payanyway_on_success_path   GET /success(.:format)  payanyway#success
payanyway_pay_path  GET /pay(.:format)  payanyway#pay
payanyway_on_fail_path  GET /fail(.:format) payanyway#fail
payanyway_on_return_path    GET /return(.:format)   payanyway#return
payanyway_in_progress_path  GET /in_progress(.:format)  
payanyway#in_progress
payanyway_on_check_path GET /check(.:format)    payanyway#check
```

Если где-нибудь вставлю ссылку на одну из этих страниц, получаю ошибку:

```
undefined local variable or method `payanyway_on_success_path'
```

Как решит эту проблему и где искать ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом `mount` вы примонтировали Engine к пути `payanyway`.
Это значит, что все маршруты, определенные в Engine, будут начинаться с `payanyway`. Страница `success` будет доступна по адресу `/payanyway/success`. И к маршрутным хелперам добавится префикс `payanyway`. Хелпер ведущий к успеху будет выглядеть как `payanyway_payanyway_on_success_path`.

UPD

Забыл написать решение.

`mount Payanyway::Engine => '/'`

Comment: Спасибо) Еще у меня были неправильные пути на сайте moneta.ru Подробнее в [github](https://github.com/ssnikolay/payanyway/issues/9)